# SQL period selection between time1 of day1 and time2 day2

Tags: sql, timestamp, db2, between

I have a table like this in DB2:

- task name
- tast_end_date in date format
- task_end_time in time format

The table contains 100s of records per day and I have to build a query to count the tasks ended from 10:00:00 of dayX to 09:59:59 of dayX+1 for the whole month.

For me the result should be like this, example:

- period 01.01.2017 time 10:00:00 to 02.01.2017 time 09:59:59, ended 25 tasks
- period 02.01.2017 time 10:00:00 to 03.01.2017 time 09:59:59, ended 25 tasks
- period 03.01.2017 time 10:00:00 to 04.01.2017 time 09:59:59, ended 25 tasks
- etc

So it`s not a simple date selection, I have to use the range of days and time at the same time... crrrrazy

I`m using dbeaver to select. thx for help!

Comment: it`s db2 (ODBC connection to AS400)

Comment: My immediate reaction to your table design is...don't store dates and times separately.  This will only cause a big headache later on (right now actually).

Comment: yes it`s true, but even using the TIMESTAMP function I can`t find out the way to select the time perion detween days

Comment: Do you need to show results just for those days that you have, or it should be always the whole month (from 1 to 30/31)?

Comment: @SergeyAn it`s good to be free to select by week, month or even year to analyze the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd build the timestamp and then adjust it so that the time falls into a single calendar day.  Then it's just a matter of counting the groups of dates..

something like so

```
with adj as (                                             
  select 
    timestamp(mydate, mytime)                          
      - 9 hours - 59 minutes - 59 seconds - 1 microsecond 
     as ts 
 from mytable                                                 
)                                                         
select month(ts), count(*) as nbr_tasks                   
from adj                                                  
group by month(ts)
```

Comment: @YuriyRadchenko glad to hear it.  Note however, it's a simple solution.  Performance is likely sub-optimal.  The expression will cause a full scan; that may be good enough if you're selecting most the rows anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a calendar table, if you're able to query on week/month/year (if not, you should create one).  Using the functions (including date math) in `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses invalidates the use of an index, which usually results in slower queries.  Instead, it's better to specify range start/end points so the system can hit indices directly.

In any case, lets add time to our date data!

Okay, we're trying to group by day, right?

```
SELECT calendarDate as start
FROM CalendarTable
WHERE calendarDate >= :rangeStart
      AND calendarDate < :rangeEnd
```

... well, okay, that gets us the start, but when querying it's helpful to have the end, or really, the start of the *next* group, as well:

```
SELECT calendarDate as start, calendarDate + 1 DAY as end
FROM CalendarTable
WHERE calendarDate >= :rangeStart
      AND calendarDate < :rangeEnd
```

So that's it for dates... except we need to add time as well!

Luckily, that's a constant value:

```
SELECT calendarDate as startDate, TIME('10:00:00') as startTime
       calendarDate + 1 DAY as endDate, TIME('10:00:00') as endTime
FROM CalendarTable
WHERE calendarDate >= :rangeStart
      AND calendarDate < :rangeEnd
```

We can wrap this up in a subquery or CTE, but what's the actual conditions used for the join?

Well, the problem is checking or ignoring the time when the date is involved:

```
task_end_date > startDate OR (task_end_date =  startDate AND task_end_time >= startTime)
```

... and for the upper bound:

```
task_end_date < endDate OR (task_end_date = endDate AND task_end_time < endTime)
```

so putting it all together looks something like this:

```
WITH QueryRange AS (SELECT calendarDate as startDate, CAST('10:00:00' as TIME) as startTime,
                           calendarDate + 1 DAY as endDate, CAST('10:00:00' as TIME) as endTime
                    FROM CalendarTable
                    WHERE calendarDate >= :startRange
                          AND calendarDate < :endRange)
SELECT QueryRange.startDate, QueryRange.startTime, 
       QueryRange.endDate, QueryRange.endTime,
       TasksEnded.ended
FROM (SELECT QueryRange.startDate, COUNT(Tasks.task_name) as ended
      FROM QueryRange
      LEFT JOIN Tasks
             ON (Tasks.task_end_date > QueryRange.startDate 
                 OR (Tasks.task_end_date = QueryRange.startDate
                     AND Tasks.task_end_time >= QueryRange.startTime))
                AND (Tasks.task_end_date < QueryRange.endDate 
                     OR (Tasks.task_end_date = QueryRange.endDate 
                         AND Tasks.task_end_time < QueryRange.endTime))
      GROUP BY QueryRange.startDate) as TasksEnded
JOIN QueryRange 
  ON QueryRange.startDate = TasksEnded.startDate
ORDER BY QueryRange.startDate
```

[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8b1a6/3/0) (Ignore the minor changes to work on a different RDBMS, the principles are sound.)

---

As a side note, this is vastly easier if you've actually stored the date/time as a single timestamp.  Assuming your calendar file still only deals in dates (which it should), just use it to construct the full timestamp, instead of separated fields:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(calendarDate, '10:00:00') as rangeStart
       TIMESTAMP(calendarDate + 1 DAY, '10:00:00') as rangeEnd
FROM CalendarTable
WHERE calendarDate >= :rangeStart
      AND calendarDate < :rangeEnd
```

... which then makes the query use only a pair of checks.

```
LEFT JOIN Tasks
       ON Tasks.task_end_stamp >= QueryRange.rangeStart 
          AND Tasks.task_end_stamp < QueryRange.rangeEnd
```

.... and which would almost certainly be faster than the mixed `AND`/`OR` required with the separated fields.

So yes, you can still query and group by date subfields, if you first construct the timestamps from the starting data.

Comment: thanks but I need the result like this for the whole year:
- period 01.01.2017 time 10:00:00 to 02.01.2017 time 09:59:59, ended 25 tasks
- period 02.01.2017 time 10:00:00 to 03.01.2017 time 09:59:59, ended 25 tasks
- period 03.01.2017 time 10:00:00 to 04.01.2017 time 09:59:59, ended 25 tasks
- etc...

anyway the result has to be on a "10:00:00 of dayX to 09:59:59 of dayX+1" bases for each day

Comment: Ah.  I thought your date format was MDY (which is the usual standard here in the US), not DMY.  Which is why it's better to use ISO (YMD), and be unambiguous.  Either way, the technique doesn't change, and the answer has been updated.